# C++ How can I insert another loop or method to make 100 equivalent to 541?

Tags: c++

My goal is to display the first list of prime numbers depending on user's input, when the user input 10, the program should display first 10 prime numbers which are 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29. I'm thinking of having generated list from 2 which is the first prime number to 541 which is the 100th prime number then if the user input for example 100 then it will be equivalent to 2 upto 541. Will my algorithm works? currently I'm able to display prime numbers from 2 - 541 and stucked on implementing another loop for 1-100 input.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
   
int main() {
    int N, counter, i, j, isPrime, n;
    cout << "List of prime numbers from 1-100: ";
    cin >> N; // if the user input 10 then the first 10 prime numbers are "2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29"
 
    // list of prime from 2-541 (or first list from 1-100 prime numbers)
    for (i = 2; i <= 541; i++) {
        isPrime = 0;
        
        for (j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (isPrime == 0 && N != 101)
            cout << i << " ";
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable. Read also a good book on C++ programming and [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Be aware that **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework website** and read wikipedia on [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Comment: Just count how many primes you already got and then break out of the loop after the `N`th prime?

Comment: To get 100 prime numbers, you must count the prime numbers when you find them (using `counter++`) and use loop condition `counter < N` instead of `i <= 541`.

Comment: Sidenote: It's rather confusing how `isPrime == 0` signals, that `i` _is_ a prime. By convention `0` is `false` and any number `!= 0` is `true`. So exactly opposite of how you are using the numbers. `isPrime` should probably be a `bool`.

Comment: There isn't *anything* you could do that would make 100 equal to 541. Your title needs clarification.

Comment: Please don't add "closed" to the title. Accepting an answer already marks your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current algorithm doesn't work, because `N` is never modified. If the user inputs `101` then nothing will be printed, because `if (isPrime == 0 && N != 101)` will always be `false`. If the user inputs anything else then it will always print the first 100 primes.

The key idea will be to count how many primes were found and break after the `N`th prime. Or count down, how many primes we still need t ofind. The rough outline will be as follows:

```
for (i = 2; N > 0; i++) {  // Loop as long as we need to find more primes
    ...

    if(isPrime == 0) {
        std::cout << ...
        N--;               // <- Found one prime, N-1 to go
    }
}
```